# Can we add javascript in IE conditional comment just before </body>

Tags: javascript, xhtml, w3c

This code should i place this code at bottom of body it's in conditional comment.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta2)/IE7.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional comments use the syntax of normal comments: **`<!--`**`[if …]>…<![endif]`**`-->`**. That’s why browsers that don’t understand them ignore them. So they can be put wherever normal comments are allowed. And the [`script` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) is allowed to be child of the [`body` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-BODY).

So you can put that conditional comment at the bottom in your `body` element.

Comment: the js file is library "IE7.js is a JavaScript library to make Microsoft Internet Explorer behave like a standards-compliant browser. It fixes many HTML and CSS issues and makes transparent PNG work correctly under IE5 and IE6. " Would it be better to put this in <head> or just before body </body>?

Comment: @jDominic Rodger - i mean where it will work better i will only use for IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Conditional comments do not have to be in the head tag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can put that code in the `<head>` tag and it will work.

But it can go anywhere.

Comment: it's a library which change browser behaviour IE6  like IE7, should i placeat bottom or at top in <head>

Comment: i know i can put in <head> but it's a best-practice to put js at bottom.

Comment: Then haven't you just answered your own question?

Comment: my question was about Conditional comment

Comment: your question after your initial question was where should you place it, followed by your comment that it's a best practice to put js at the bottom, answering it.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <!--[if lte Gecko 3.1]><script type="text/javascript">    
Cufon.replace('.cufonised p, H2');
    </script>  <![endif]-->
```

Could this work?